# IIS rewrite rule to replace sub domain url to different url on same domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I want to match pattern only if below url contain **'/reports'** if yes then below url : 
https://test.website.com/reports/abc/sample.PDF

should be replace only with sub domain, like : 
https://test2.website.com/reports/abc/sample.PDF

without changing extra parameters or page names.
this url content can be dynamic, which we cannot fix hardcoded in rule : **reports/abc/sample.PDF**

Answer (score 0):

Use the **BeginRequest** on **Global.asax**, there check your request path, and act according - this is an example base on your question.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;    
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    if (cTheFile.Contains("/reports/") && cTheFile.Contains("https://test."))
    {
        app.Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace("https://test.","https://test2."), true);
        return;     
    }
}
```

be ware to avoid any endless loop here.